# How can I change the text of a page's Label in Xamarin.forms from the Android MainActivity.cs file?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, label

I'm working with Xamarin.forms and I'm trying to display the phone number (of the Android phone that's running it) on a Label in the current page. The thing is that I'm not being able to do the change from the MainActivity of Android neither can get the phone number with the respective page.xaml.cs code.

Does somebody know a way to do this? (I think it's simple stuff, but I'm pretty much a noob)

Here is the code of the Android MainActivity.cs file (the phone number is saved in "myPhoneNumber"):

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android.Content;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SOSChile.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SOSChile", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        string myPhoneNumber = "Hola";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());


            TelephonyManager tMgrStart = (TelephonyManager)this.GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
            string myPhoneNumber = tMgrStart.Line1Number;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the page.xaml.cs file (I haven't modified it, but maybe helps to understand the situation :P):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SOSChile
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AndroidPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AndroidPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use the XF DependencyService to access Android specific features from your XF code

Comment: or, get the phone number first, then pass it as an argument to App()

Comment: I like the second option better, but how do I do it? That's what I'm trying to know :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only way seems to be DependencyService (at least, it's the only I found). There are enough tutorials in youtube and it's not that hard, but my main trouble was that I didn't know that I should use "Android.App.Application.Context" instead "this" as a context

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use `Messaging Center`.

Subscribe the message in your Forms， for example:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, object>(this, "PassData", (sender, args) =>
        {
             DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + args, "OK");
        });
    }
```

And send messages on the specific platform:

```
string myPhoneNumber = "test";
MessagingCenter.Send<object, object>(this, "PassData", myPhoneNumber);
```

Comment: I had read about this, but didn't know how to make it work. I'll give it another go in the future ;)

Comment: You can just copy these codes to the right place. It's so easy.